# how to get count of not-null value based on specific field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have elastic search index and I need total count of records that one of fields ("actual_start")  is not-null how can I do this?

I have wrote this query and I want to append count of not-null actual start value to the result of my query:

```
 $params = [
            'index' => "appointment_request",
            'body' => [
                'from' => $request['from'],
                'size' => $request['size'],
                "query" => [
                    "bool"=>[
                        "must" => [

                            [
                                "term" => [
                                    "doctor_id" => [
                                        "value" => $request['doctor_id']
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "match" => [
                                    "book_date" => $request['book_date']

                                ]
                            ],
                      
                        ]

                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

Try this:

```
GET <your-index>/_count
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "actual_start"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can read the `count` value which will give you the total count of records that `actual_start` is not-null.

You can also replace `_count` with `_search` and `total` value under `hits` will give you a total count (in case you also want the `hits`) .

If you want to do the opposite (all records which `actual_start` is null):

```
GET <your-index>/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "actual_start"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I understand you correctly you want to append your current query with the `exists` query.

Example:

```
GET <your-index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          <put-your-query-here>
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "actual_start"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but i have another query and I need to append count of not-null value of actual_start field to it, also i need total to have count of all records in my index whould you please help me how can i do it?

Comment: Can you please share your query? what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean "append count of not-null actual start value to the result of my query"? if you want the count result of not-null actual_start you will have to run the `exists` query as a different query. Elastic Search doesn't support subqueries. If you intended to filter your query with the not-null  actual_start field then use the query I've written under my update.

Comment: If you find my solution helpful please feel free to upvote/accept the answer.